# Python coverage from processes started separately

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-coverage, ros

I have a [ROS](https://www.ros.org/) application that starts several different processes with different ros nodes. As well as this I have some scripts (that start this node) that also run some python scripts. Here is a simplified example:

*Server Launch File*

```
  <node pkg="ui" name="hmuiserver" type="server.py" launch-prefix="$(eval 'python3-coverage run --source=/opt/project/')"/>
```

*Start Script*

```
if python3-coverage run /opt/proj/lib/feature_set.py; then
    echo "Feature Enabled!"
fi

cmd="roslaunch ui hmui.launch"
$cmd
```

When I run this start script, I get a coverage report from `python-coverage` that covers the scripts run through the server.py (the ros launch file). But I do not get coverage from the `feature_set.py` script.

If I use `run --parallel-mode` on both then I only get the coverage from the `feature_set.py`, not from the launch file (yes i am doing `python3-coverage combine`).

I am guessing this is going to be to do with some multiprocess stuff. **What settings do I need to use to capture the coverage of both files in this scenario?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what ROS is, but if you have more than one process, you need to be careful to keep their measurement separate.  The `parallel` option and [`coverage combine`](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.4/cmd.html#cmd-combine) might be what you need.

Comment: I will update the question, because i found this already, but it doesn't work for just the things coming from the ROS launch file.